# CSS display:table with fractional pixel width

Tags: html, css

I am using percentages to create the width of a `div` with the `display` property set to `table`. In my case, the width of the parent `div` is 88.7969px. So it stands to reason that setting the `width` of child `div` with the `display` property set to `table` to 100% would compute the width to be 88.7969px. This, however is not the case. It computes the width to be 88px.

Is a fractional pixel width of `table` displays not supported?

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/36fn415a/). If you inspect the elements, you'll see the `content` wrapper at 88.7969px but the inner child `div` at 88px.

[image: wtf]

Comment: On Firefox both are `88.8px` wide.

Comment: Hmmm, this is Chrome but good to know

Comment: It seems that it's a Chrome bug (or "missing feature"): https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=377847

Answer (score 1):

No there is nothing to do with `display:table` with a fractional pixel value.

It completely depends upon the **Browser** and **Browser Version** which you are using.

Current Versions as of 9 FEB 2016::: on Google Chrome the div with fractional pixel value with `display:table` is rounded up, while in Firefox it is not and also in IE it is not rounding up.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Not to my knowledge if documented. Just from experiments on browsers am saying.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a fractional width, on an element with `display: table`, is rounded down, rather than to the nearest neighbour, as it would be expected otherwise.